# 乱数で表示した100個の0～9の整数それぞれの出現回数をアスタリク(*)で表示したい

Tags: java

**ソースコード**

```
int[] frequencies = new int [10];
int[] ar1 = new int[100];

for(int i = 0; i <  ar1.length; i++) {
    ar1[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
    System.out.println(ar1[i]);
    int array =ar1[i];
    frequencies[array]++;
```

メソッドを使って0~9の整数それぞれの出現回数を*で表示したいのですがどうしたらいいか分かりません...

**例**

```
6, 8, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 5, 6, 9, 3, 0, 6, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 8, 6, 
3, 3, 6, 0, 6, 5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 3, 6, 4, 1, 6, 1, 0, 7, 7, 2, 
2, 6, 5, 1, 1, 8, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 1, 6, 5, 3, 6, 8, 5, 9, 4, 
5, 9, 1, 9, 8, 6, 0, 7, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 6, 1, 8, 5, 8, 4, 3, 
3, 6, 8, 4, 2, 6, 9, 7, 6, 3, 7, 7, 2, 8, 5, 0, 9, 9, 2, 4
```

```
0: *****
1: ********
2: *********
3: *************
4: ***********
5: ***********
6: *******************
7: ********
8: *********
9: *******
```

Comment: コードの言語はJavaのようにみえますが、タグにはjavascriptとjavaの二つがあります。JavaScriptはJavaと全く違う言語なのですが、どのような関係があるのでしょうか？関係が無い場合は、タグから削除してください。

Comment: もうすこし、わからない部分を具体的に書けないでしょうか？このままでは「どうしたら良いのですか？」に対して「Javaやプログラミングそのものを学んでください」ぐらいしか、適切なアドバイスができません。「アルゴリズムや処理のフローがわからない」「出力方法がわからない」「Javaのコンパイル方法がわからない」「mainメソッドの書き方がわからない」等、『何』がわからないのかを明記してください。

Comment: @らっしー 残念ながら質問者のアカウントは削除済みのようです。

Comment: @cubick なんとういうか・・・そのままいなくなってしまってはどうしようもないですね。せめて、この質問を見た人にちょっとだけでも役に立ちそうな回答だけでもしておこうと思います。

Answer (score 1):

質問者はいなくなってしまいましたが、せっかく調べて"*"を出す部分だけでも作ったので、興味がある人の参考に僅かでもなれば幸いです。

```
(new java.util.Random()).ints(100, 0, 10)
    .boxed()
    .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy(
        java.util.function.Function.identity(), java.util.stream.Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> e.getKey() + ": " + "*".repeat(e.getValue().intValue()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

少しだけ解説。

`Random#ints()`は乱数のIntStreamを作るメソッドです。それを`collect(...)`でグルーピングしながら、カウントしています(この部分は、色々参考にして書いたので、ちょっとよくわかっていない)。なお、`boxed()`でIntStreamをボックスしてStreamにしないとダメのようです(直接する方法はあるかも知れない)。あとは、普通のStreamにして`map(...)`で文字列に使えて、出力するだけとなります。なお、文字列の繰り返しに使っている`String#repeat()`はJava 11かららしいので、Java 11でないと動作しません。

`for`文を使うより、慣れればこっちの方が速いと思っています。ただ、JavaのStreamは使いづらい部分がちょっとあるので、普段から使うかは微妙ですが。(普段はJavaをほとんど書いていないので、なんとも言えません。)

Answer (score 0):

表示にフォーカスして、元の値をとってはいません。必要であれば、
修正してください。

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] frequencies = new int[10];
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ++frequencies[Math.abs(rand.nextInt()%frequencies.length)];
        }

        for(int i=0; i<frequencies.length;i++){
            System.out.println(creteMessage(i,frequencies[i]));
        }

    }

    public static String creteMessage(int index,int number){
        String msg;
        StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
            stb.append("*");
        }

        return msg=String.format("[%02d]:%s", index,String.valueOf(stb));
    }
}
```

処理結果は以下の通りです。

```
[00]:*****
[01]:**********
[02]:**********
[03]:******
[04]:**************
[05]:************
[06]:*************
[07]:************
[08]:**********
[09]:********
```

Comment: 質問が上手く書けているかどうかとその質問の出自は分けて考えるべきなのではというメタでの議論があるのを思い出しました：[学校の宿題は回答するべきでしょうか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/19110)

Comment: なるほど。ご指摘ありがとうございます。今回、課題ではないかとコメントしたのは、課題であるならばそれなりにフィットさせないと使えないことを伝えたかっのですが、なるほど議論にはなりそうな話ですよね。せっかく伏せてある寝た子を起こすような真似をしてしまいました。該当の記述は削除します。